# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' - Sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I've trained a chatbot with some data from a csv. All the tçdatabase and model are working ok, it can predict the tag of a sentence, but I want that the chatbot predicts the tag of an input.
Here is the code (is a sklearn pipeline):

```
while True:
  usr_inp = input("Tú: ")
  X_predict = train_test_split(usr_inp , test_size=0.1 , random_state=12)
  prediction = pipeline.predict(X_predict)
  print("Prediction: " , prediction)
```

and it gives this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-db8a012d9786> in <module>()
     47   usr_inp = input("Tú: ")
     48   X_predict = train_test_split(usr_inp , test_size=0.1 , random_state=12)
---> 49   prediction = pipeline.predict(X_predict)
     50   print("Prediction: " , prediction)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py in _preprocess(doc, accent_function, lower)
     66     """
     67     if lower:
---> 68         doc = doc.lower()
     69     if accent_function is not None:
     70         doc = accent_function(doc)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

the model:

```
#Model & Pipeline

model = LogisticRegression(C=25 , solver="saga" , max_iter=2000)
pipeline = Pipeline([("tfidf" , vectorizer) , ("clf" , model)])

pipeline.fit(X_train , X_test)
```

Could someone help me plis?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `X_predict` is likely a list of strings, thus has no `lower` attribute. If you have access to the `pipeline.predict` source code, you can change it to a list comprehension.

```
doc = [item.lower() for item in doc]
```

If not, you should look at the documentataion of `pipeline.predict` which I'm guessing takes in a string parameter. If so, you can `join` the list into a string